# Connect UIImageView to view controller display image from Images.xcassets with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

Sorry for the simplicity of this question, but I seem to be missing something on all the other similar questions.  I have dragged in a UIImageView to a storyboard.  I then created an Outlet named mainImage in my view controller.  I have three images sets in my Images.xcassets named 0, 1 and 2.

How do I display one of my images in my UIImageView using Swift.  Eventually I will want to randomly pick an image but for now I'd like to learn how to display one.

Comment: Just set the according image property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an image you can use `UIImage(named: "imagename");`

e.g.

`mainImage.image = UIImage(named: "imagename");`

make sure that you place the correct image name.

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried this before but I put it outside the viewDidLoad function.  Thanks for a clear answer!